# Disambiguate [python-pulsar] from Apache Pulsar Python client

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I've noticed that in Stack Overflow questions, [python-pulsar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-pulsar) is described as:

> Event driven concurrent framework for python.
>
> With [pulsar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pulsar) you can write asynchronous servers performing one or
> several activities in different threads and/or processes.

and the link is to a PyPi Python package.

However, it appears that the last time that package was referenced by this tag was in 2017. All of the questions using this tag since then have been referring instead to the Apache Pulsar Python client.

Can we either repurpose this tag or rename it to [pulsar-web-python] and create a new one for [apache-pulsar-python]? What's the right way to approach this situation?

Note: The Apache Pulsar project has been experiencing considerable growth, so I anticipate this being more of an issue in the future.

Comment: Do we really need another tag, though? Is there anything specific about the Python client that wouldn't be enough to just use [tag:python] together with [tag:apache-pulsar]?

Comment: Is the client for the same technology? If so, I'm not convinced that a separate tag is warranted. People with expertise in the server side are probably going to know something about the client side, too, and the reverse won't be uncommon either. Having expertise in both sides of the technology will result in more exposure for questions and probably better answers.

Comment: The old "pulsar" thing seems super dead. The repository is archived, and the website just says "Buy this domain". It is definitely not related to Apache Pulsar.

Comment: There's a very different feature set and development lifecycle for the Pulsar Python client compared to the main Java client. There are also some implementation-related differences, such as related to Prometheus instrumentation, and there are different people who support the different clients. There's also a Go client and a .NET client and some unofficial clients.